# TensorFlow tensor not reshaping properly

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have created a script that mirrors the one described in TensorFlow's *Deep MNIST for Experts* tutorial found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros).

However my script returns an error quite early on when it tries to reshape the x tensor from the dimensions `[-1,28,28,1]` into the dimensions `[-1,28,28,1]`. I am confused as the tutorial does the same thing with success however it throws the following error for me:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (100, 784) for Tensor 'Reshape:0', which has shape '(?, 28, 28, 1)'
```

My python script in full is here below:

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
import tensorflow as tf


x = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, shape = [None,784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, shape = [None, 10])


W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,1,32]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32]))
```

This is where I suspect the error occurs:

```
x = tf.reshape(x,[-1,28,28,1]) 

output1 = tf.add(tf.nn.conv2d(x,W1, strides =[1,1,1,1], padding = "SAME"), b1)
output1 = tf.nn.relu(output1)
output1 = tf.nn.max_pool(output1, ksize = [1,2,2,1], strides = [1,2,2,1], padding = "SAME")


W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,32,64]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64]))


output2 = tf.add(tf.nn.conv2d(output1,W2, strides = [1,1,1,1], padding = "SAME"), b2)
output2 = tf.nn.relu(output2)
output2 = tf.nn.max_pool(output2, ksize = [1,2,2,1], strides = [1,2,2,1], padding = "SAME")
output2 = tf.reshape(output2, [-1, 7*7*64])



W_fc = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([7*7*64,1024]))
b_fc = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024]))


output3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(output2,W_fc), b_fc )
output3 = tf.nn.relu(output3)
output3 = tf.nn.dropout(output3, keep_prob = 0.85)


W_final = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024,10]))
b_final = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10]))


predictions = tf.add(tf.matmul(output3,W_final), b_final)


cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = y_  ,logits = predictions))
optimiser = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cost)


sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()



for i in range(7000):
    batchx_s,batchy_s = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    sess.run(optimiser, feed_dict = {x:batchx_s, y_:batchy_s})


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(20000):
        batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
        optimiser.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})


correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(predictions, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
```

.

```
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images,y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you call the `run` method of your session, including the `feed_dict` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed your code and it should work properly.

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
import tensorflow as tf


x = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, shape = [None,784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, shape = [None, 10])


W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,1,32]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32]))

x_image = tf.reshape(x,[-1,28,28,1]) 

output1 = tf.add(tf.nn.conv2d(x_image,W1, strides =[1,1,1,1], padding = "SAME"), b1)
output1 = tf.nn.relu(output1)
output1 = tf.nn.max_pool(output1, ksize = [1,2,2,1], strides = [1,2,2,1], padding = "SAME")


W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,32,64]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64]))


output2 = tf.add(tf.nn.conv2d(output1,W2, strides = [1,1,1,1], padding = "SAME"), b2)
output2 = tf.nn.relu(output2)
output2 = tf.nn.max_pool(output2, ksize = [1,2,2,1], strides = [1,2,2,1], padding = "SAME")
output2 = tf.reshape(output2, [-1, 7*7*64])



W_fc = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([7*7*64,1024]))
b_fc = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024]))

output3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(output2,W_fc), b_fc )
output3 = tf.nn.relu(output3)
output3 = tf.nn.dropout(output3, keep_prob = 0.85)


W_final = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024,10]))
b_final = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10]))


predictions = tf.add(tf.matmul(output3,W_final), b_final)


cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = y_  ,logits = predictions))
optimiser = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cost)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(predictions, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))



with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(20000):
        batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
        if i % 100 == 0:
            train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})
            print('step %d, training accuracy %g' % (i, train_accuracy))
        optimiser.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})
    print('test accuracy %g' % accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels,}))
```

Your main issue was the line -

```
x = tf.reshape(x,[-1,28,28,1]) 

output1 = tf.add(tf.nn.conv2d(x,W1, strides =[1,1,1,1], padding = "SAME"), b1)
```

The objective of a placeholder is only to feed data to a target tensor; it should'nt be treated like a normal tensor. 
I have also removed the redundant calls to variable initializer and running optimizer -

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()


for i in range(7000):
    batchx_s,batchy_s = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    sess.run(optimiser, feed_dict = {x:batchx_s, y_:batchy_s})
```

The above looks as though they come from some place else :)
Finally, I've added some print statements adapted from said tutorial, its always good to know how your training is performing real-time

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you are running the graph, you are not giving the input values (`mnist.test.images`) to the input placeholder, because you have assigned the result of a different operation to `x` (in your code I can see `x = tf.reshape(x,[-1,28,28,1])`, but probably there is some other assignment somewhere else, because the error message suggests an addition operation with shape `(?, 10)`). TensorFlow allows you to feed values for *any* tensor in the graph (not just placeholders), so it thinks you are trying to replace some intermediate result with your input. Simply rename the Python variable holding the input tensor to something like `x_input` in both its definition and the `run` call, and be careful not to overwrite it later.

Comment: Hi I re-ran it and found that the shape error it is referring to is '(?, 28, 28, 1)'.

Comment: @spicyburrito You have to change `x` to `x_input` both when you create the palceholder and when you call `run`. You are still trying to feed a value for the reshape operation, not for the placeholder.

Comment: I have however it throws the same error in the 'for i in range(7000)' for loop

Comment: Thanks I replaced all the x's with x_inputs which is why the error just repeated. Thanks a million